# How to do inheritance with singleton

Tags: c#, inheritance, singleton

I want to know how to inherit from a class 'BaseClient' that has a singleton and be able to use same instance of basic members from base class singleton in the inherited class too.

```
public class BaseClient
{
    protected string _url;
    protected string _username;
    protected string _password;

    private static BaseClient _instance;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    public static BaseClient Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new BaseClient(true);
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }

    public void SetInfo(string url, string username, string password)
    {
        _url = url;
        _username = username;
        _password = password;
    }

    public string GetVersion()
    {
        //MyService is a simple static service provider
        return MyService.GetVersion(_url, _username, _password);
    }
}

public class Advanced : BaseClient
{
    private static AdvancedClient _instance;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    public static AdvancedClient Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new AdvancedClient(true);
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }

    public void DoAdvancedMethod()
    {
        MyService.DoSomething(_url, _username, _password);
    }
}
```

So if I use BaseClient.Instance.SetInfo("http://myUrl", "myUser", "myPassword"); and then AdvancedClient.Instance.DoAdvancedMethod(), the AdvancedClient singleton will use the same base member instance as the BaseClient singleton?

Comment: Aren't singletons supposed to be sealed? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573492/should-we-seal-singletons-should-we-try-to-inherit-from-singletons-in-the-first

Comment: How are you proposing that they should be the same instance, when they're not even the same type?

Comment: +1 for locking to make it thread safe, -1 for locking on *every* request. Use double-check locking instead. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

Comment: Building from dbaseman's point, I think your best bet is to wrap the base singleton rather than inherit from it (which doesn't make sense).

Comment: Thanks for the double-check locking Matt ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just kidding :) here's my solution:

I simply use an independent class to store the shared members and on AdvancedClient singleton creation, retrieve the BaseClient one.

```
public class ClientInfo
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class BaseClient
{
    protected ClientInfo _info;

    private static BaseClient _instance;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    public static BaseClient Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new BaseClient(true);
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }

    public ClientInfo Info
    {
        get
        {
            if(_info == null)
            {
                _info = new ClientInfo();
            }

            return _info;
        }
    }

    public void SetInfo(string url, string username, string password)
    {
        Info.Url = url;
        Info.Username = username;
        Info.Password = password;
    }

    public string GetVersion()
    {
        //MyService is a simple static service provider
        return MyService.GetVersion(Info.Url, Info.Username, Info.Password);
    }
}

public class Advanced : BaseClient
{
    private static AdvancedClient _instance;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    public static AdvancedClient Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new AdvancedClient(true);
                    _instance._info = BaseClient.Instance.Info;
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }

    public void DoAdvancedMethod()
    {
        MyService.DoSomething(Info.Url, Info.Username, Info.Password);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just came across this when dealing with a similar problem, but how does your answer differ ultimately from making a static class named Global with a readonly property of type ClientInfo? As far as I can tell, this just pretends the singleton means anything. It's fairly bad design either way.

Answer (score 3):

I've always found it much easier to implement this type of solution using a generic:

```
public class Singleton<T> where T : class
{

    protected Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static T Instance
    {
        get { return SingletonFactory.instance; }
    }

    public void SetInfo(string url, string username, string password)
    {
        ...
    }

    public string GetVersion()
    {
        ...
    }

    class SingletonFactory
    {

        internal static readonly T instance;

        static SingletonFactory()
        {
            ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(
                       BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                       null, new System.Type[0],
                       new ParameterModifier[0]);

            if (constructor == null)
                throw new Exception(
                    "Target type is missing private or protected no-args constructor: type=" + 
                    typeof(T).FullName);
            try
            {
                instance = constructor.Invoke(new object[0]) as T;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    "Failed to create target: type=" + typeof(T).FullName, e);
            }
        }

    }

}

public class Advanced : Singleton<Advanced>
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: you miss lazy intialization

Answer (score 0):

You could change the meaning of the singleton in your base class to something like this:

```
public static BaseClient Instance
{
    get
    {
        lock (padlock)
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = (BaseClient)(new AdvancedClient(true));
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does BaseClient knows about AdvancedClient?

Comment: Well, this was two years ago, I'd think AdvancedClient would inherit from BaseClient. If you mark conflicting methods with `new` when you cast down to BaseClient, you will invoke the old methods. Otherwise if you want to upgrade the logic of your BaseClient methods, make them virtual, and override them in the AdvancedClient.

Answer (score 0):

Since `_instance` is private in both classes these are two different variables. `_instance` would have to be protected in order to be shared. The derived class cannot access a private member of the base class!