# Returning a singleton from one method call

Tags: c#, .net, singleton

I have this class:

```
public static class GameControl
{
   public static DNControl GetDayNightControl()
   {
      return DNControl.Instance;
   }

   public static MapHandler GetMapHandler()
   {
      return MapHandler.Instance;
   }

   public static TemperatureControl GetTemperatureControl()
   {
      return TemperatureControl.Instance;
   }
}
```

where all of the return types are Singletons.Can any of you guys can give me an idea how can i return any of them with one single method?

Comment: A static class cannot inherit from a base class (nor can it implement an interface). As a workaround, you could try the suggestion from this SO question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962499/how-to-do-inheritance-with-singleton

Comment: It's not really clear to me what it is you are trying to do. Can you give an example of how you'd like your code to look?

Comment: Ehm, why not allow the calling class to grab the singleton instances directly instead of through these methods? Otherwise just leave it like it is, it's good enough abstraction.

Comment: I agree with Brain - either you've oversimplified your example to the point where it's no longer obvious what you're trying to achieve, or you want to do something counterintuitive - any chance you could explain more?

Comment: Ok then i am using this class to get from those Singletons some variables or methods like for example my GUIClass uses: GameControl.GetTimeControl().Days.ToString(), other classes uses for example the TemperatureControl singleton like: GameControl.GetTemperatureControl().Temperature, so i was trying to get those from one single method

Comment: @MamaTate I don't believe there's any value added. If you did a single method, you'd end up with something like `GameControl.MyMagicMethod<MapHandler>().DoStuff()`. What's the benefit over `MapHandler.Instance.DoStuff()`? Those are singletons, you don't need to wrap access to them - it's always the same object one way or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a wrapper class and return that instead.

```
public class WrapperClass
{
    public DNControl DayNightControl {get; internal set;}
    public MapHandler MapHandler {get; internal set;}
    public TemperatureControl TemperatureControl {get; internal set;}
}

public static class GameControl
{
    public static WrapperClass GetEverything()
    {
        var wrapper = new WrapperClass();

        wrapper.DayNightControl = DNControl.Instance;
        wrapper.MapHandler = MapHandler.Instance;
        wrapper.TemperatureControl = TemperatureControl.Instance;

        return wrapper;
    }

    // if that's still pertinent you may keep your individual methods too
}
```

I should mention though: I really do not see the point of keeping those together to begin with. There may be a larger picture I'm not seeing here but it seems to me that your actual way of simply being able to call your individual singletons from a static class is fine as it is. You may benefit from giving more details on the added value you expect out of this.

Comment: Of course, while this does technically answer the literal question, it's going to be *less* convenient for the caller to use than just having 3 different methods (you're just tacking on an extra call to `GetEverything` in addition to whatever you'd have done before), so I don't know why anyone would actually use this...

Comment: @Servy That being said, I don't see the point of the original methods neither

Comment: Fair enough.  The only reason I could see it would be if they returned interfaces and the underlying classes were private/internal.

Comment: I have to agree with both of you here. At this point either something is wrong with the OP's design or there's a greater picture we're not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use generics, e.g.

```
public static T GetControl<T>()
{
    // determine what type to return based on T, and return it
}
```

I've not tried it out, but off the top of my head, I think something like that should work.

Comment: Might be a problem if one control inherits from another.

Comment: That depends on how you determine the type to return, it can be a problem, yes, but not one that can't be taken into account.

Comment: Right, which is why I've mentionned *might*. ;) Also there could still be a problem if two instances were of the same exact type. Not the case for now but that's still something to think of.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this with reflection

```
public static class GameControl
{

    public static T GetControl<T>()
    {
        return (T)typeof(T).GetProperty("Instance").GetValue(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes i like this solution, but the bad thing is that i am using some of those singletons at runtime and i will get probably performance hit.I think i will try a wrapper.

Comment: @MamaTate how could you *not* use those singletons at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you're asking, but one way to return all in one method call would be

```
public static class GameControl
{

    public static void GetSingletons(out DNControl dnControl, out MapHandler mapHandler, out TemperatureControl tc)
    {
        dnControl = DNControl.Instance;
        mapHandler = MapHandler.Instance;
        tc = TemperatureControl.Instance;
        return;
    }

}
```